# My Controller and Area Name is same, if i want to call Default Controller Method which has action same name of Controller Inside Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have created One simple MVC App.

I have one Controller namely **HelathController**.

In this HealthController I have two methods namely **Index** & **BodyMass**

Now I have Created One Area Namely **Health**

In this area I have Controller Namely **BodyMassController**

This BodyMassController have a method **Index**.

I do not change anything routing file.

Below is My **HelathController**

```
 public class HealthController : Controller
 {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        // GET: Health
        public ActionResult BodyMass()
        {
            return View();
        }
  }
```

This is My BodyMassController Which Is Inside **Health** Area.

```
  public class BodyMassController : Controller
  {
            // GET: Health/Health
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return Content("Hello " + text);
            }
   }
```

This is My AreaRegsitration Code.

```
  public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
  {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Health_default",
                "Health/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
   }
```

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
     FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
     RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);          
     BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Now When I Use Url **/Health** It will call Automatically HelathController's Index method.

Now When I Use Url **Health/BodyMass** It will call Automatically BodyMassController's Index method In HelathController Area.

If I want to Call HelathController's BodyMass(), What Should i need to do?

Comment: Well you have a conflict here, you need to fix it. I would suggest renaming something.

Comment: is there any other way to resolve it?

Comment: Any method you use will just be horribly hacky, just be safe and rename things.

Comment: try this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs   but i will also suggest renamig although you can achieve your goal using constraints thanks

Comment: You have 2 URLs which are the same and that is (as already mentioned) a conflict. The user doesn't care what is going on in the background. If you have 2 pages sitting on `/health/[whatever]` something needs to change. For example, you could rename your `Area`, your `Health` controller OR you could apply a custom route to any of the conflicting URLs to make the URL needed to arrive at the page differ.

Comment: so basically, there is no alternative of this issue, i need to rename one of them.

Comment: unfortunately yes, this is the best (and really only feasible) way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Need add this in your RouteConfig.cs file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "HelathControllerIndex",
    url:  "Helath",
    defaults: new { controller = "Helath", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "BodyMassControllerIndex",
    url:  "Health/BodyMass",
    defaults: new { controller = "BodyMass", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```